# Content is not loaded into div using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How come the content form the "body.html" file isn't loaded into the "section2"-div?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert("Document ready");  

        $.get("body.html", function(data){
            alert("Data Loaded: ");
            $("#section2").html(data);
        });
});

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="section2">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

body.html:

```
Content for all!
```

Both alerts are triggered.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What happens when you call  `alert("Data Loaded: "+ data);`?

Comment: It outputs "Data Loaded: [object XMLDocument]"

Comment: try to explicitly set the datatype: `$.get("body.html", function() {}, "html");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the response headers content type has to be "text/html" when calling body.html.

To avoid errors, use :

```
$.ajax({
    url:"body.html",
    dataType: "text/html",
    success: function(data){
        $("#section2").html(data);
    }
});
```

or

```
$.get("body.html",function(data){
        $("#section2").html(data);
    }
, "text/html");
```

or

```
$("#section2").load("body.html");
```

Comment: Ah, I see. When using php I do encode the content form the server. I guess that's why it works. Is it possible to encode the data on the server side when NOT using PHP?

Answer (score 1):

i'd use load() instead

```
 $("#section2").load("body.html")
```

EDIT - i'v seen that $.get works also with two parametrs so i just leave the load() advice

Comment: This doesn't matter. Have a look at the examples in the jQuery docs, where it shows this working with 2 parameters: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ (But agreed, `load` is the better option here!)

Comment: That second argument is optional; the `$.get(url, success function);` syntax is perfectly valid.

Comment: Thank you, using "$("#section2").load("body.html")" solved the problem. But I really don't get it because I do exactly the same as in my example in a different application. The only difference is that I use php to echo the content to the calling function. Can that really make a difference?

Comment: No it should make no difference. in any case in this scenario load() is a better option i think

Comment: The problem was due to the content-type. Do you mind sharing what the benefit using load compared to get is?

Comment: Basically load is a shorthand function for what you needed to do: using it means less typing and writing code that's more readable. but that's only my opinion! :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) documentation. It looks like jQuery is trying to help you out by sending the data back as a JS XML document, when you really want HTML. Try `$.get(<url>, null, <successFunc>, "html")` (see the documentation on the [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method for more on those parameters)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

All I did was link to the external jquery and changed what file I was calling...

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script> 
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert("Document ready");  

        $.get("serverTime.php", function(data){
            alert("Data Loaded: ");
            $("#section2").html(data);
        });
});

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="section2">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```